# G separable group, $\aleph_0 \leq \tau$. What is $l(X)$ and $\omega l(X) (\leq \tau)$? where $X \subseteq G$. And what is $\chi (G)$ (cardinal)?

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, set-theory, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

Happy Chinese new year!

I was reading (and translating) a Russian article "On the topological groups close to being Lindelöf".
Where it is assumed G is a separable group and $\tau \geq \aleph_0$

**Theorem 1.** Let a topological group G satisfy one of the following conditions:

1. G is algebraically generated by a subset $X \subseteq G$, where $l(Х) \leq \tau$ ;
2. G is topologically generated by a subset $X \subseteq G$, where $l(Х) \leq \tau$ ;
3. $ωl(G) \leq \tau$.
   Then ...

I'd like to know the definition of **l(X)** or where can I find this notation and definitions?

[Here is the original text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCq8s.png)

[Here is another notation I'd like to know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkTov.png)

What is the definition $\chi (G_1)$ or where can I find it?

This is what I found but I'm no sure if it applies to my case:
[Posible definition of χ($G_1$)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRuDc.png)

[And if this χ has the same definition?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS7pQ.png)

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $l(X)$ is the Lindelöf number: the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that every open cover of $X$ has a subcover of size $\leq\kappa$. I've never seen $\omega l(X)$ before.

Comment: $\chi(X)=\sup_{x\in X}\{\chi(X,x)\}$ is (as your screenshot says) the character of $X$, where $\chi(X,x)$ is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that $x$ has a local basis of size $\leq\kappa$ (of course in a topological group $\chi(G,x)=\chi(G,y)$ for all $x,y\in G$)